# C++ - object which can be owned or shared in the same class

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, smart-pointers, ownership

I have a class (PackRequest), which contains some container (EventPack). Depending on the use, this container can be owned by the class object, or can be provided from some external source.

In particular, whole object is transferred to another process, and thus have to be serialized. So in the sending process it is provided from some external source, and then only serialized and transferred. In the receiving process, we have to restore it from the serialized data - and thus, we have to create and own it.

I solved it with very simple solution, but I don't like it fully:

```
class PackRequest : public Request {
    private:
        unique_ptr<EventPack> owned_pack_;
        EventPack *pack_;

    public:
        PackRequest(EventPack *pack=nullptr)
            : pack_(pack) {}

        void serialize() override;
        void unserialize() override;
};
```

Then serialize/unserialize functions are as follow:

```
void PackRequest::serialize() {
    auto size = pack_->serialized_size();
    data_msg_ = make_unique<zmq::message_t>(size);
    pack_->serialize_bin(data_msg->cdata(), size);
}

void PackRequest::unserialize() {
    owned_pack_ = make_unique<EventPack>();
    pack_ = owned_pack_->get();
    pack_->unserialize_bin(data_msg_->cdata(), data_msg_->size());
}
```

And then at the sending side owned_pack_ is nullptr, and pack_ is provided in constructor - so we don't own the object, we just serialized it into data_msg_ and send. At the receiving side we get the same data in data_msg_ - so we create new object which is owned by us (kept in owned_pack_), and then deserialize it from data.

Now, it works and is short - but I'm not sure if it's the best approach - especially, it's using not-smart pointer which I don't like. So do you have an idea for something being more according to the modern C++ rules?

Comment: I was thinking about instead of both pointers maybe use shared_ptr with reference count artificially increased for the case we don't own the referenced EventPack - but I didn't find the way to manually manipulate the reference counter in shared_ptr.

Comment: I think this question is better suited to Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kompas when the object is owned by someone else, what do you want to happen if that object ceases to exist while it's still pointed to? Or can you prove that such situation cannot happen?

Comment: @user2079303: I can guarantee it won't happen (I know, it's kinda risky, but in this point performance is more important).

Answer (score 0):

Since you can guarantee that the raw pointer is always valid (when it's used at all) there is no need for a smart pointer, and your current implementation is just fine.

Another option would be to use a `shared_ptr` in the external source, and a single `shared_ptr` in `PackRequest`. That adds a dependency on how the object is stored in the external source (must be a `shared_ptr`) and has some small overhead for the reference counting, but on the other hand, you never need to test which pointer has the data.